# Comparing two columns in excel, inserting blank rows and moving associated data

Tags: excel

[image]

I entered the Cells in Column A, B, C, D, AND I Want the result as entered in F, G, H, I, so what formula i should insert i the cells

Comment: I think what you are doing here could also achieved with a macro, since your are inserted a line every time there is a credit... Then you could re-run a macro for a selected range...

Comment: My answer is completely fine with your question. Please do not change the whole setup (change the picture) to ask another question. Better ask a NEW question. I rolled back THIS question to its original because users are not allowed to change (edit) a question to ask a **different** one.

Answer (score 1):

F3 would be:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(ROW()-2,A:A,0)),"",ROW()-2)
```

And G3:

```
=IF(LEN(F3),INDEX(B:B,MATCH(F3,A:A,0)),"")
```

copy F3:G3 to H3:I3 and "auto fill" down as you need to

[image]

Comment: this formula is not working when there are four collumns

Comment: it does what you requested... but should also work with 4 columns... you just need to adjust the ranges...

Comment: I have done that, but it insert some collumns where it is not needed, i mean neither there is debit side nor credit side

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a macro instead, then just copy this code into a module in visual basic editor and run it.

```
Sub insertRows()
Columns("G:J").EntireColumn.Delete

Dim lrow As Long: lrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim brng As Range: Set brng = Range("A1:D" & lrow)
brng.Copy Range("G1"): Range("G1").Value = "After"
Dim arng As Range: Set arng = Range("G3:G" & lrow)
Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In arng
  If rng <> rng.Offset(, 2) Then
      If rng > rng.Offset(, 2) Then
        rng.Resize(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      Else
        rng.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      End If
  End If
Next rng

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

OMG, this one is difficult but these are the formulas you can try:

From `cell F3`:

```
=IF(AND(N(F2)=0,F2<>""),1,IF(AND(NOT(COUNTIF($A$3:$A$22,MIN(INDEX($A$3:$A$22,MATCH(MAX(F$2:F2,H$2:H2),$A$3:$A$22,1)+1),INDEX($C$3:$C$22,MATCH(MAX(F$2:F2,H$2:H2),$C$3:$C$22,1)+1)))),INDEX($A$3:$A$22,MATCH(MAX(F$2:F2,H$2:H2),$A$3:$A$22,1)+1)),"",INDEX($A$3:$A$22,MATCH(MAX(F$2:F2,H$2:H2),$A$3:$A$22,1)+1)))
```

From `cell G3`:

```
=IF(N(F3),INDEX(B:B,MATCH(F3,A:A,0)),"")
```

From `cell H3`:

```
=IF(AND(N(H2)=0,H2<>""),1,IF(AND(NOT(COUNTIF($C$3:$C$22,MIN(INDEX($C$3:$C$22,MATCH(MAX(H$2:H2,F$2:F2),$C$3:$C$22,1)+1),INDEX($A$3:$A$22,MATCH(MAX(H$2:H2,F$2:F2),$A$3:$A$22,1)+1)))),INDEX($C$3:$C$22,MATCH(MAX(H$2:H2,F$2:F2),$C$3:$C$22,1)+1)),"",INDEX($C$3:$C$22,MATCH(MAX(H$2:H2,F$2:F2),$C$3:$C$22,1)+1)))
```

From `cell I3`:

```
=IF(N(H3),INDEX(D:D,MATCH(H3,C:C,0)),"")
```

Basically, the formulas are very similar under both `Debit` and `Credit` columns but just swapping the range references.  Try and let me know.